# drawing circles on a map while the user is scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, scroll

I would like to build a very similar (duplicate) as this one. Just the first part where circles show up on the map. Any ideas where I can start? Any jquery plugins that do this?

https://www.airbnb.com/annual

If there aren't any plugins can you give guidance where I should start? Any examples are greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind an event handler to the `scroll` event. Get your position from `$(window).scrollTop()`, and with this information draw and/or resize your array of circles as needed.

There are ways to get the effect on the site without Canvas. You can use `position:fixed` divs with high `border-radius` to create circles, and you can resize them and reposition them with JQuery. You can also use SVG, with which you can create an array of all the circle objects at radius 0 initially and increase or decrease the radius with the scrolling effect (or your data set). If you do use canvas, you may need to be prepared to re-render the entire canvas on every scroll tick, since it will be difficult to get the circles to "shrink" otherwise. This will probably make your scrolling choppy, just as it is for me on the site.